# cast string to timestamp millisecond

Tags: google-bigquery, casting, timestamp

I´m need transform this string `"Wed, 29 Mar 2023 12:20:45.474"` as timestamp. How do this?

I try `PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S.%f', 'Wed, 29 Mar 2023 13:27:43.764')` but its not work

Comment: Try this instead. `PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%E3S', 'Wed, 29 Mar 2023 13:27:43.764')`

Answer (score 0):

The issue in parsing to timestamp is with the %f. The %f does not exist in the formating.

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a, %e %b %Y %H:%M:%S', 'Wed, 29 Mar 2023 13:27:43')
```

You could potentially split the string on the dot and then add milliseconds.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a, %e %b %Y %H:%M:%S', split('Wed, 29 Mar 2023 13:27:43.764',".")[offset(0)]), INTERVAL  CAST(split('Wed, 29 Mar 2023 13:27:43.764',".")[offset(1)] as int64) MILLISECOND)
```